# Retorno dados Json

Tags: c#, json, mvc, asp.net-core

Tenho esta função para retornar os dados em JSON, porém não to conseguindo fazer ela funcionar em MVC Core.

```
 public ActionResult SalvarItens(string HoraInicio, string HoraFim, bool Seg, bool Ter, bool Qua, bool Qui, bool Sex, bool Sab, bool Dom, bool Fer, int Tipolimite, int Limiteacessos, int HorarioId)
        {
            var item = new HorariosItens()
            {
                HoraFim = HoraFim,
                HoraInicio = HoraInicio,
                Seg = Seg,
                Ter = Ter,
                Qua = Qua,
                Qui = Qui,
                Sex = Sex,
                Sab = Sab,
                Dom = Dom,
                Fer = Fer,
                Tipolimite = Tipolimite,
                Limiteacessos = Limiteacessos,
                HorarioId = HorarioId,
            };

            try
            {
                _context.HorariosItens.Add(item);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            //return Json(new { Resultado = item.Id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Este `return Json(new { Resultado = item.Id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` não funciona em MVC COre, como posso converter para funcionar?

Comment: Você não precisa do `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`

Comment: Eu trabalho com MVCCore, não aparece esta opção pra mim.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar do mesmo nome o método `Json(object data)` no `Microsoft.AspNeCore.Mvc.JsonResult`, que não implementa o argumento do `JsonRequestBehavior` que estava presente `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult` e acabava sendo necessário retornar o Json quando o acesso à action era realizado através de um `POST`.

```
public ActionResult SalvarItens(string HoraInicio, string HoraFim, bool Seg, bool Ter, bool Qua, bool Qui, bool Sex, bool Sab, bool Dom, bool Fer, int Tipolimite, int Limiteacessos, int HorarioId)
{
    var item = new HorariosItens()
    {
        HoraFim = HoraFim,
        HoraInicio = HoraInicio,
        Seg = Seg,
        Ter = Ter,
        Qua = Qua,
        Qui = Qui,
        Sex = Sex,
        Sab = Sab,
        Dom = Dom,
        Fer = Fer,
        Tipolimite = Tipolimite,
        Limiteacessos = Limiteacessos,
        HorarioId = HorarioId,
    };

    try
    {
        _context.HorariosItens.Add(item);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return Json(new { Resultado = item.Id });
}
```

Comment: Não consigo colocar o return Json, ele não reconhece, e me retorna o erro.  que json não existe no contexto atual.

Comment: qual versão do dotnet core? `SalvarItens()` é uma `ActionResult` ou uma `Task<IActionResult>` ?

Comment: Consegui resolver, fazendo desta forma: return Content("new { Resultado = item.Id }");

Comment: Isso vai lhe retornar uma string, não o seu objeto serializado

Comment: Mas da forma que me auxiliou ele não reconhece o Json, Tem alguma referência que deveria fazer ?

Comment: Qual classe a sua controller está herdando? Ps.: Esse método está em uma Controller, certo?